# SceneJS graphing examples

Tags: json, webgl, graphing, scenejs

Are there any good open source SceneJS examples that can graph functions similar to those demonstrated in http://www.graphycalc.com/?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any but it should be relatively easy to simply use a custom vertex shader that transforms the vertices of a grid into your desired function: https://github.com/xeolabs/scenejs/wiki/shader

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a data source plugin with a geometry node, to continually update it's mesh:
http://scenejs.org/examples.html?page=geometryPluginPullStream
http://scenejs.org/examples.html?page=geometryPluginPushStream

And here's the available vertex deformation examples (selected by tag, see left column, click one to load it):
http://scenejs.org/examples.html?tags=vertexDisplacement